# Change the right hand text in the VS Code suggest widget

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making a theme for VS Code ([you can find it here if you're curious](https://github.com/njshockey/all-blue-theme) but it's not overly important for this question), but one part in particular is driving me up a wall. I can change the rest of the suggest widget that shows up when you start typing just fine.

```
// Editor widget
"editorWidget.background": eC.bgSideBar,
"editorWidget.foreground": eC.fg,
"editorWidget.resizeBorder": eC.borderBright,
"editorSuggestWidget.foreground": eC.fg,
"editorSuggestWidget.background": eC.bgStatusBar,
"editorSuggestWidget.border": eC.borderDim,
"editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": eC.selectionBright,
"editorSuggestWidget.selectedForeground": eC.fgTertiary,
"editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": eC.fgFourth,
"editorSuggestWidget.focusHighlightForeground": eC.fgFourth,
"editorGhostText.foreground": eC.fgDisabled,
```

But I can't find the value to change the right hand side of the suggest widget text anywhere in the [VS Code API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

[image: Text that I'm trying to change the color of]

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is the same `ThemeColor` as the main selected text foreground:

```
"editorSuggestWidget.selectedForeground": "#fff",
```

It does not appear to be a separate themeable item.  And I don't see a relevant issue so you may have to file one yourself.

Comment: Just tried this. Yeah. They are the same color. That's really annoying but thanks for figuring that out. Running this by the VS Code devs may be a good idea though. (VS Code is currently at v1.81.0 for me.)